# Issue while applying underline and strikeThrough

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm having a `contentEditable` div where I put all my content inside of it. When I'm applying **underline** and **strikeThrough** or toggling them then it breaks.

Sample HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
     #editor{
       background-color:yellow;
     }
</style>

<head>
    <script>

     function apply(style) {
         if (style == 'strike') {
             document.execCommand('strikeThrough')
         } else {
            document.execCommand('underline')   
         }
     }
        
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id= 'editor' contentEditable="true" ></div>
    <button onClick='apply("strike")'>strike</button>
    <button onClick='apply("underline")'>underline</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Enter some character.
2. click **underline** and **strike** (Enable styles)
3. Enter some character.
4. click **underline** (Disable style)
5. Enter some character. Now it breaks.

I'm experiencing this issue only in Safari.

Comment: What means *"it breaks"* can you be more descriptive?

Comment: The styles (underline, strike) not applying properly that's what i meant as "it breaks".